# How to show single item selected in recyclerview using kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

How can we mark single item is selected in `Recyclerview` using kotlin. When I select an item and after that click on other item then previously selected item should be dis-selected.Here is my adapter class in kotlin:..

```
 class ListAdapter(var context: Context, var list: ArrayList<ListModel>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(v)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        holder?.bindItems(list[position])
    }

    class MyViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

        fun bindItems(items: ListModel) {
            itemView.txt_que.text = items.que
            itemView.txt_ans.text = items.ans
            itemView.txt_sr_no.text = items.srNo
        }
}`
```

Comment: You can manage boolean variable in model class for this purpose..whenever you select any item make that boolean variable true and all other items boolean variable false...

Comment: @Lokesh Desai
i have tried this. but, i am not understand where i set the boolean value. because in java we have setter/getter for set or get values but in kotlin we dont have setter/getter.

Comment: Who told you there is no getter and setter in kotlin? There is getter and setter in kotlin...Please check this link inform me if you don't understand
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html

Answer (score 4):

Here `dataItem` is Model Class and please take one extra Boolean variable `isSelected` in model class (default value is false) and true when select item then true this variable on selected position,
below are example :

```
class AllModuleListAdapter(
var context: Context?,
private var moduleList: ArrayList<DataItem?>?,
private var mCallback: DeviceClickListener
) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<AllModuleListAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val context = parent.context
    val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_modules, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return moduleList?.size ?: 0
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(moduleList?.get(position))

    if (moduleList?.get(position) is DataItem) {
        val dataItem = moduleList?.get(position) as DataItem
        if (dataItem.isSelected) {
            context?.let { ContextCompat.getColor(it, R.color.colorOrange) }
                ?.let { holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(it) }

        } else {
            context?.let { ContextCompat.getColor(it, R.color.white) }
                ?.let { holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(it) }

        }
    }

}

inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    init {
        itemView.constraint_main.setOnClickListener {
            val list = moduleList as List<DataItem>
            for (item in list.indices) {
                list[item].isSelected = false
            }
            list[adapterPosition].isSelected = true

            mCallback.onDeviceClick(adapterPosition)
            notifyDataSetChanged()

            context?.let { it1 -> ContextCompat.getColor(it1, R.color.colorOrange) }?.let { it2 ->
                itemView.constraint_main?.setBackgroundColor(it2)
            }

        }

    }

    fun bind(module: DataItem?) {
        itemView.txtModuleName?.text = module?.id.toString()
        itemView.txtSignal?.text = module?.room
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: bro it's too late, i have done it approximate 1.10 years ago, but thanks for the solution.:)

Answer (score 2):

```
        if (mPosition == position)
        {
            //set selected here
        } else
        {
            //set unselected here
        }

        holder.parentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                mPosition = position;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Write above code in onBindViewholder and declare mPosition as global int variable in adapter class

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:- take one variable in your ListModel class as

```
var selected:boolean  = false
```

then while setting the listModel items set this value as false as

```
for(int i=0;i<listModel.size;i++){
   listModel.get(i).selected = false
}//this is for setting all values false
```

when you select any item from list call this method and then set selected = true for selected position and simply refresh the adapter list.

in your adapter check for this selected value and accordingly set the check box value inside your bindItems method

```
  itemView.checkBox.selected = items.selected//this will set your checkbox selected value
```