# Selected Items gets unselected after scrolling in Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I made an adapter to show a number of cities where we have to select them. However, when i scroll down and go back up again the selected items are de-selected again.

I tried setting sethasStableIds to true but that did not work either

```
public class CitiesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CitiesAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "CitiesViewAdapter";

private List<Cities> citiesModelList;
private Context mContext;
private OnClickListner mOnNoteListner;

public CitiesAdapter(List<Cities> citiesModelList, Context mContext , OnClickListner mOnNoteListner) {
    this.citiesModelList = citiesModelList;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mOnNoteListner = mOnNoteListner;
    setHasStableIds(true);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CitiesAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cities_listitems, viewGroup , false);
    CitiesAdapter.ViewHolder holder = new CitiesAdapter.ViewHolder(view , mOnNoteListner , this);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CitiesAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    Log.d(TAG , "onBindViewHolder: called.");

    Cities citiesmodels = citiesModelList.get(i);
    viewHolder.tvCitiesName.setText(citiesmodels.getName());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return citiesModelList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position)
{
    return position;
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    TextView tvCitiesName;


    OnClickListner onClickListner;
    private CitiesAdapter citiesAdapter;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView , OnClickListner onClickListner , CitiesAdapter citiesAdapter) {
        super(itemView);
        tvCitiesName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCitiesName);
        this.onClickListner = onClickListner;
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        this.citiesAdapter = citiesAdapter;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onClickListner.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(),citiesAdapter.getItem(getAdapterPosition()));
    }
}

public Cities getItem(int i){
    return citiesModelList.get(i);
}

public interface OnClickListner{
    void onItemClick(int position , Cities cities);
}

}
```

I have a pasted my adapter below. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in adavnce

Comment: Please follow this link=> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707969/how-to-show-single-item-selected-in-recyclerview-using-kotlin/58450264?noredirect=1#comment103238371_58450264 it may help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selected items in RecyclerView change on scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39724352/selected-items-in-recyclerview-change-on-scrolling)

Comment: everytime you scroll up and down onBindViewHolder() executed and render the particular row, its seems your checkbox showing the default selection option, i.e. false. add the boolean property on Cities model for checkbox and update the prop on checked/un-checked

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707969/how-to-show-single-item-selected-in-recyclerview-using-kotlin/58450264?noredirect=1#comment103238371_58450264

Answer (score 1):

On the `Cities` object, define a boolean property called `selected` and use a method to determine if it is selected by using a getter such as `boolean isSelected()`. Then, on your Adapter's `onBindViewHolder` method add something like this:

```
{
    // Code to add inside onBindViewHolder.

    if (cityModel.isSelected())
    {
         // Select the view you want to select.
    }
    else
    {
         // Deselect the view.
    }
}
```

Always use an if-else condition to avoid incorrect results.

Answer (score 0):

This happen because of when we scroll onBindViewHolder method call.

```
//create integer list for selected city or if there is only one selected city then create variable selected city
private List<integer> SelectedcitiesModelList= new ArrayList<integer>() //in adapter class

// now assign tag to tvCitiesName in onBindViewHolder method 
 viewHolder.tvCitiesName.setTag(i); //to identify the view and i is position

//now in onclick method get textview tag and put in list or variable
SelectedcitiesModelList.add(viewHolder.tvCitiesName.getTag())

//now go to onBindViewHolder method 
for(int p;i<SelectedcitiesModelList.size();p++)
    {
        if(p==i)    
        {
            //this is your selected item
            //do what you want to   
        }   
    }
```